# Are `std.debug.print()` calls removed in `ReleaseSafe` and `ReleaseFast` compilation modes?

Tags: compiler-optimization, zig

I ask to understand if it makes sense to leave the code with a bunch of `std.debug.print()` calls spread around the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, naked `std.debug.print` calls are not removed at any level of optimization. Of course, they could be removed if they occur in a code branch that the optimizer decides can be removed.

Regarding leaving the code *"with a bunch of std.debug.print() calls"*: unless you are *testing* compilation in a release mode, don't. `std.debug.print` is intended for debugging; code that is compiled for release shouldn't have these. Not that this would hurt anything, but leaving scattered debug print statements throughout the body of a release code base is just bad style.

Instead you should be using functions from `std.log` if you want logging in release builds, and you should be using a writer to standard output to deliver messages to the user of a program.

Answer (score 2):

The default Zig logging APIs are not removed or disabled in release builds.  But in Zig, the formatted logging calls are relatively easy to wrap, and comptime lets you relatively easily determine if the code is in release mode, so you can create your own "develOnly" logging API if you want:

```
const std = @import("std");
const builtin = @import("builtin");

// debug logs that are removed from Release builds
pub inline fn develPrint(fmt: []const u8, args: anytype) void {
    if (builtin.mode != .ReleaseFast and builtin.mode != .ReleaseSmall) {
        std.debug.print(fmt, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not compile with v0.11.0 or v0.12.0-dev.876: where is `builtin.mode` coming from? Could you provide a complete example program that compiles and runs?

Comment: Oops, good point. I can probably get away with leaving out "std", but including the imports is more complete.

Comment: I had looked in the `std.builtin` docs and found nothing; importing the `builtin` package works. Sometimes Zig namespaces can be a little confusing.

Comment: Why `if (builtin.mode != .ReleaseFast and builtin.mode != .ReleaseSmall)` instead of just `if (builtin.mode == .Debug)`?

Comment: This is what the question explicitly asked for.   But yeah, depending on your application's definition of "release mode" it might be simpler use `== .Debug`.  (At the moment the only difference is what happens for `ReleaseSafe` mode.)